# The largest of $N$ random numbers over a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

So I read somewhere than if you have $N$ numbers picked independently from a uniform distribution, say $[0,1]$, the greatest number has an expected value of $\frac{N}{N+1}$. So if you have 2 numbers the greatest has expected value $2/3$. The smallest has expected value of $1/3$. The expected values are uniformly distributed. This makes sense, but is there a clear/intuitive proof of this? Thanks :)

Comment: We can *calculate* and find quickly that  the answer is indeed $\frac{N}{N+1}$. There is an intuitive argument that leads to the correct answer. I am slightly uncomfortable with it, since the intuition can do strange things when we deal with probabilities.

Comment: that's so true ! it seems with many of the probability problems I've came across AndreNicolas there are two inutively correct ways to think about it and solve it. this means my probability of getting it right is what ? 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $U_1 , ... , U_N$ be the $N$ random variables from the uniform distribution. Let $X$ be their maximum. We will in fact compute the distribution of $X$, that is

$$F(t):= \mathbb P(X < t) .$$

The maximum of $N$ numbers is less than $t$ if and only if all $N$ of them are less than $t$. Therefore

$$\mathbb P(X < t) = \mathbb P(U_1 < t , ... , U_N < t).$$

Since the $U_j$'s are independent, this is the same as

$$\mathbb P(U_1 < t) ... \mathbb P(U_N < t).$$

If $t \in [0,1]$, then since $U_j$'s are uniformly distributed we get

$$F(t) = t...t = t^N.$$

Hence the density of $X$ is $F'(t) = N t^{N-1}$ on $[0,1]$. So, the mean of $X$ is

$$\int_0^1 t\cdot Nt^{n-1} dt = \frac{N}{N+1}.$$

EDIT: The general case of the expectation of the $k$th largest of $N$ random variables follows from a similar argument. Here one uses that if $Y$ is the $k$th largest of $N$ independent random variables, then $Y$ is less than $t$ if and only if $k$ of the random variables are less than $t$ and $N-k$ are greater than or equal to $t$ (and there are $N$ choose $k$ ways for this to happen).

Comment: I think the OP is asking the general case, i.e. the expected value of the $k$th largest of $U_1,\ldots,U_N$ is $\frac{N-k+1}{N+1}$. So, the expected values of the ordered uniform distribution is ``uniform,'' (so the OP says) with a spacing of $\frac{1}{1+N}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to calculate the $E^N_1(U_k)$, where $U_k$ is the $k$th largest number out of $N$ numbers independently and uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$. Assuming we've already proved that $E^N_1(U_N)=N/(N+1)$ (see user15464's proof). Now let's look at $E^N_1(U_{N-1})$:

Given that the largest number is $t^\prime$, the expectation value of the second largest number out of $N$ uniform random numbers in $(0, 1)$ is then equal to the expectation value of the largest number out of $N-1$ numbers uniformly distributed between $0$ and $t^\prime$:

$$
E^N_1(U_{N-1})\vert_{U_N = t^\prime}= E^{N-1}_{t\prime}(U_{N-1})
$$

And $E^{N-1}_{t\prime}(U_{N-1})$ obviously just scales with $t^\prime$:

$$
E^{N-1}_{t^\prime}(U_{N-1})=t^\prime E^{N-1}_1(U_{N-1})=t^\prime (N-1)/N
$$

Now to remove the condition on $t^\prime$:

$$
E^N_1(U_{N-1}) = E(E^N_1(U_{N-1})\vert_{U_N = t^\prime}) = E(t^\prime (N-1)/N) = E(t^\prime)(N-1)/N
$$

Recall that $t^\prime$ is the largest number out of $N$ numbers in $(0, 1)$, so $E(t^\prime)$ is just $E^N_1(U_N)$. There you have:

$$
E^N_1(U_{N-1}) =  \frac{N-1}{N}E^N_1(U_N)
$$

Now you can deduce the general formula for $E^N_1(U_k)$:

$$
E^N_1(U_k) = \frac{k}{k+1}\frac{k+1}{k+2}\ldots\frac{N}{N+1} = \frac{k}{N+1}
$$

Which also holds for $k=N$.

Comment: This happens to give the right answer but I'm not sure it is a safe way to reason. All the numbers are drawn from a uniform distribution, but just as the greatest number is no longer uniformly distributed *given that it is the greatest*, each of the other numbers is no longer uniformly distributed *given that it is not the greatest*.